# Jade: How to have an empty line in an output HTML?

Tags: html, pug

I want to have an empty lines between sections, comments and tags. I'm using jade to output my html and can't output empty lines. Here is what I want.

```
<div>
  <div class='another'>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  I want a line just like above
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are couple of options that worked for me:

The [`=` operator](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/) (which enters an evaluated piece of code) with the string for newline character `'\n'`

```
div
    div.another
= '\n'
div I want a line...
```

The [`|` pipe operator](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) (which enters plain text) with a space. (had to be two of them for some reason..

```
div
    div.another
|    // < followed by blank spaces
| 
div I want a line...
```

Comment: I couldn't get the `= '\n'` trick to work. The `|  ` trick (pipe followed by blank spaces) works, but relying on trailing whitespace is fragile -- if you teach your editor or source control system to strip or reject trailing whitespace, which is common practice, this becomes more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#{}`-style interpolation to generate the empty string:

`| foo
  | #{''}
  | bar`

(tweaked lightly from a suggestion in https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/912)

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you the HTML output you have asked for:

```
div
    div.another

div
   | I want a line just like above
```